# Match short- or full-form command line option

Tags: regex

I'd like to match any combination of `-v` or `--verbose`, including things like `-vd path` or `-av`, but don't want to match anything other than short-form options with a `v` or `--verbose` itself. So far I have the following:

```
--verbose|-[^-]v
```

Here are some examples to match:

```
-v
-vv
-vd path -v
-vd path --version
--skip-dependencies -vd path --version
-vd path --verbose
-av
-vvv
--verbose
```

Currently, the only things that match are the following:

- `-vv`
- the first `-vv` of `-vvv`
- `--verbose`
- `-av`

I also want to match `-v`, the entirety of `-vvv`, and `-vd`.

Comment: Most languages have a function for parsing command-line options. This is probably better than trying to use ad hoc regular expressions.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm in a situation where I've had to split up two instances of the same parser, as I require the verbose option a little earlier in my program than the other options. I don't want to have to define entire classes in the command-line parser function, for example.

Comment: what language are you using to check command line options?

Comment: You can make the pattern more specific `--verbose\b|(?<!\S)-(?:av+|v+d|v+)` https://regex101.com/r/GudYNw/1

Comment: @Grobu: Python; I'm currently using `click` to parse the options.

Comment: @the-fourth-bird: Yep; that works perfectly. Thanks! Can you post it as an answer so that I can mark it as correct? EDIT: Wait; doesn't seem to work in python. Should've seen this coming...

Comment: @the-fourth-bird: Wait again; the `\b` after the `--verbose` seems to have been messing with the python version of the expression. It's working perfectly now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a more specific version of the pattern:

```
--verbose\b|(?<!\S)-(?:a?v+|v+d)\b
```

**Explanation**

- `--verbose\b` Match `--verbose` followed by a word boundary to prevent a partial word match
- `|` Or
- `(?<!\S)` Negative lookbehind, assert a whitespace boundary to the left
- `-` Match literally
- `(?:a?v+|v+d)` Match either an optional `a` char followed by 1+ times a `v` char OR 1+ times a `v` char followed by a `d` char
- `\b` A word boundary

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UrQcgD/1).

Comment: Alright, so a minor change I made was converting the `(?:a?v+|v+d)` to `(?:.?v+|v+d)`, as `-a` was just an example, but otherwise, perfect! Thanks so much!